# Vendor plugin images missing in my rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yarnpkg

I'm trying to integrate the Unite Gallery plugin into my rails app.

I add the plugin using Yarn and I reference the CSS and the JS in my application.
Everything is fine, except for the images that are referenced in the CSS file using `url:`

They are missing.

Rails look for the images in `http://localhost:5000/images/play_button.png` but of course images are in the node_modules folder.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you find an answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, but I was able to get it working by just adding the extension to the end of the require.

So in my `application.css` I added `.css` to the end of each filename and boom!

```
@import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
@import "leaflet-fullscreen/dist/leaflet.fullscreen.css";
```